# Magento Cron Job is not working using module

Tags: magento-1.9, cron, crontab

I am new to Magento and trying to run Cron Job using module.

Here is my code
  **app/etc/modules/FQLabs_Automail.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <FQLabs_Automail>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </FQLabs_Automail>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/FQLabs_Automail/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
    <FQLabs_Automail>
        <version>0.1.0</version>    <!-- Version number of your module -->
    </FQLabs_Automail>
</modules>

<crontab>
    <jobs>
        <fqlabs_automail_send>
            <schedule>
                <cron_expr>*/5 * * * *</cron_expr>
            </schedule>
            <run>
                <model>automail/observer::doSomething</model>
            </run>
            </fqlabs_automail_send>
        </jobs>
    </crontab>

</config>
```

**app/code/local/FQLabs_Automail/Models/observer.php**

```
<?php 
class FQLabs_Automail_Model_Observer
{

    public function doSomething()
    {
        Mage::log("This is a cron run test", null, 'mylog.log');
        return $this;
    }


}

?>
```

After clearing cache and re indexing indexes, I hit (www.yourstore.com/cron.php)
I have done everything right but still the log is not working.
Please suggest some help.
Module Link for Debug is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/t9g72j07pxnecqf/Mymodule.rar?dl=0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***app/code/local/FQLabs_Automail/Models/observer.php***

is wrong, should be

**app/code/local/FQLabs/Automail/Model/Observer.php**

Refresh your configuration cache and you should then confirm that your module cron task is enabled in Magento, you can look for this in the database but I recommend you install the AOE Scheduler module http://fbrnc.net/blog/2011/03/magento-cron-scheduler

This will give you a detailed graphical view of all magento cron tasks, you should also see your cron job there if your module is configured properly.

You can manually schedule the cron job to run with AOE Scheduler and check your system log file for the output. Running cron.php from your browser will not necessarily run the job, as you have scheduled it to run every 5 mins.

This should help you troubleshoot the problem further.

Comment: No I do not see any entry in the database. I have written code properly so what mistake I am making? Last time I try to install that I was getting error.

Comment: remove the frontend router and define automail as suggested here. If that doesn't work zip your module up and upload it so that I can install and debug it.

Comment: I have added the the link to download the module. Thanks

Comment: Your model class folder is named models instead of model. I have installed your module with the correct model folder name and it is working : 2015-08-18T14:26:01+00:00 DEBUG (7): FQLabs_Automail_Model_Observer

Comment: I changed the file name. Did you Run cron.php after uploading module?

Comment: Running cron.php manually will not create any output, your cron schedule is set to run every 5 mins. If your system cron job is configured correctly after 5 minutes you will see the output. You can easily confirm all this using AOE Scheduler.

Comment: Also if your system log is enabled you would have seen the error being generated to tell you that FQLabs/Automail/Model/Observer.php was not found.

Comment: Its not getting installed properly. So I avoided it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27094/discussion-between-paj-and-akshay-taru).

Answer (score 2):

There are few issues in your model

### Wrong Folder structure :

`FQLabs_Automail` is `not single folder`. It should be two different folders (FQLabs and Automail)

- `FQLabs` call as `Module NameSpace`
- `Automail` call as `module Name`

folder structure must be `app/code/local/FQLabs/Automail` for config.xml and Observer.php

**app/code/local/FQLabs_Automail/etc/config.xml**

should be

**app/code/local/FQLabs/Automail/etc/config.xml**

- Models should be Model

`observer.php be Observer.php`

**note:
First letter of file should be Uppercase for model,block and helper ,controllers files**

Comment: Thanks for correction. But code does not execute and create a log file

Answer (score 1):

You need to define `automail` or Magento won't know what it's referenced to. In your `config.xml`, add the following:

```
<global>
   <models>
     <automail>
       <class>FQLabs_Automail_Model</class>
     </automail>
   </models>
</global>
```

Also, make sure that the logs are enabled, or else it will execute it, but never write to log.

Comment: I added this and yes logs are enabled but still not running.

Comment: Set up your Magento cron in your server cron, and make it run every minute. If it skips the time, Magento will mark it as `Too late` and won't run. (for example, if it's scheduled for 12.05, cron.sh has to run at that EXACT time)

Comment: How to do it? And I hardly understood what you are trying to say that Too Late part of magento and How to set up and all. I am new in Magento

Comment: Google is your friend: http://support.xtento.com/wiki/Setting_up_the_Magento_cronjob

Comment: Tried not working.

Comment: Okay I have added above code my cron.php is running but there are no mylog.log file in logs. So Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

[@Amit Bera's](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/79064/5443) answer is correct.
Though if you want to use Magento's cron mechanic, you'll have to run `cron.php` (which is located in your root folder).
Try and run it every five minutes as a cronjob on your server, otherwise all Magento crons won't get registered in table `cron_schedule` (which is also a way of making sure your cron has been queued) and thus won't get triggered/executed.

Comment: I have tried to run cron.php manually by hitting the (www.yourstore.com/cron.php) but i do not see entry of that cron in the table `cron_schedule`. Please assist me to find whether Am I missing something.

Comment: but have you seen other crons being put into that table?

Comment: Lets continue discussion in chat

Comment: Yes I did, Now its working fine. I reinstalled AOE Scheduler and its cron, Now it is working fine, Thanks for the help

Comment: Alright, glad we managed to help, thumbs up always appreciated if it helped :)
On a side note, try managing your crons server side, I know it can be a tedious task, but you're better off not cluttering Magento with tons of extensions.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<global>
        <models>
            <automail>
                <class>FQLabs_Automail_Model</class>
            </automail>
        </models>
    </global>

    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <automail>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>FQLabs_Automail</module>
                    <frontName>automail</frontName>
                </args>
            </automail>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
    <crontab>
        <jobs>
            <automail>
                <schedule>
                    <cron_expr>*/5 * * * *</cron_expr>
                </schedule>
                <run>
                    <model>automail/observer::doSomething</model>
                </run>
            </automail>
        </jobs>
    </crontab>
```

let me know if it's working or not?

Comment: a frontend router is not needed for this.

Comment: @paj Of-course, we don't know where his using right?

Comment: what's wrong with this answer. why some one down vote for this?